# Limiting case of Binomial(n,p)/n?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let the random variable $X$ have distribution $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$.  Let $Y = X/n$.  What is the limiting distribution of $Y$, as $n \to \infty$?  Does it have a simple distribution?

Of course, when $n$ is large, $X$ has approximately the distribution $\text{Poisson}(np)$.  Thus, we could ask the question in the following alternative way: suppose $X^* \sim \text{Poisson}(np)$, and define $Y^* = X^*/n$; what is the limiting distribution of $Y^*$, as $n \to \infty$?

I have not been able to find an existing result on this, though it sounds like the sort of thing that someone must have studied long ago.  When I search for limiting distribution and Poisson or limiting distribution and Binomial, I find many references to the fact that $\text{Binomial}(n,p) \to \text{Poisson}(np)$ as $n \to \infty$, which I already knew, so I'm not sure where to look to figure this out.

Comment: The central limit theorem should help here.

Comment: This special case of the CLT is sometimes called the [de Moivre-Laplace Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem)

Comment: Sorry but there is not a iota of CLT in here. The limiting distribution exists and is a Dirac delta at p.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Rename the random variable $X$ as $X_n$ and the random variable $Y^*$ as $Y_n$, and note that one can assume without loss of generality that each $X_n$ is $X_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nZ_k$ where the sequence $(Z_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli with parameter $p$.

Then $Y_n=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nZ_k$ hence the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) applies, which tells you that...

Answer (score 2):

A standard approximation for the binomial distribution says that $X$ has approximately a Gaussian distribution, i.e., $X \sim \mathcal{N}(pn,p(1-p)n)$.  It follows that $Y$ also has approximately a Gaussian distribution, i.e., $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(p,p(1-p)/n)$.  This approximation becomes better and better as $n \to \infty$.  The limit as $n \to \infty$ is a Dirac delta at $p$.

Comment: What are the meanings of the assertions that X and Y have "approximately Gaussian distributions" with varying parameters? How is the approximation of Y_n by N(p,p(1-p)/n) "better" when n is large? Please provide **precise mathematical statements**. (But the last sentence of the post is OK.) // Upvoter: why the upvote?

Comment: @Did, I do understand that those statements are not considered precise in a mathematical setting, if that is what you were hinting at.  I'm just writing down what was helpful to me.  In my application, I needed an engineering approximation more than I needed a precise mathematical statement.  (I'm not saying I don't value precise mathematical statements; I do.)  If you don't find that useful, that is certainly entirely your prerogative; I completely understand.  Thanks much for all your help!

Comment: Why (and in which sense) is the approximation of $Y_{20}$ by $N(p,p(1−p)/20)$ "better" than the approximation of $Y_{10}$ by $N(p,p(1−p)/10)$, if indeed this is what you mean (in an engineering context)?